# Star Wars: Republic Heroes does not save my game

Tags: games-for-windows-live, star-wars-republic-heroes

I've purchased Star Wars: The Clone Wars - Republic Heroes for PC.

I am facing an issue in the game play; once I play through the game, quit it and come back, there is no option to continue or load saved games. I am forced to start new campaign all over again.

I've played a lot of games and I tried a lot of things but nothing is working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I revised the title to aid searchability for others, but had a typo that I went back to revise and upon doing so, my change description disappeared so I thought it had created a new revision for the typo correction and sadly it had not. I apologize for that change description reading typo, but now it won't let me correct it.

Answer (score 1):

According to several sources and my own personal experiences with Games for Windows Live (sometimes Microsoft, I just don't know what to do with you), **[you must create/sign into a profile in the Windows Live overlay at startup if you want to save your game](http://forums.lucasarts.com/thread.jspa?threadID=142249&tstart=-4). It can be an offline profile if you like, but you must sign in with a profile to save.**

As per [the manual](http://cdn.steampowered.com/Manuals/32420/TCWRH_G4W_Manual_Final.pdf?t=1270602388), the main menu contains a "Continue" entry with which to load your game if the game has been saved. According to multiple sources, it would appear that regardless of platform, [the game saves upon completing a mission](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/960120-star-wars-the-clone-wars-republic-heroes/answers?qid=125859). **If you have yet to complete a mission, this could also be the issue that you are experiencing**, but as the missions are so brief, this seems highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sign in to Xbox Live. If you don't have an Xbox Live account, you may create one on Xbox.com :-)

Comment: This doesn't really add anything that the existing answer hasn't already covered